# How can I create a playable monster in DnD 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, new-players

In the 3.5e we had the level adjustment, but I didn't find it or any rule talking about it, on the 5e.

How can I create a Vampire or a Lycanthrope or a Half-Dragon? There is a mention about "as player" but there is no restriction or "how to" to make my own character.

Comment: Have you read the section in the DMG on creating your own custom race?

Comment: I read that, but I don't what to have all the trouble to make my own race. And if I whant to create the Vampire, with all the aspects, it will be lvl 1? or as in 3.5, will have some adjustment to be used?

Comment: Actually, better yet, both of the things you mention have PC rules in the Monster Manual.

Comment: You're a player, right? Not the DM?

Comment: My friends and I are reading the rule books to understand the possibilities and start to play. Thanks for your help, but use the MM it's not good, Dragonborn Half-Dragon(each of an color) could be OP...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two options here:

- Create a template (or use one of the templates provided by the monster manual). For Vampires it's outlined on pg 295, for Lycanthropes it's outlined on pg 207, half dragon is outlined on pg 180.
- Use the custom race construction rules on dmg pg 285-287.

These provide the by the book rules for these possibilities. There is no LA in 5e.